# Jenkins add build number to jar name

Tags: jenkins, gradle

We've got a gradle project that I'm building on my jenkins. We want to append the build number to the jar before archiving the artifact. As in:

Original name: `ProjectName-v0.1(-sources).jar`

Archive name: `ProjectName-v0.1(-sources)-BUILD_NUMBER.jar`

We want to do it entirely using jenkins, no gradle plugins, as we still want to be able to build without jenkins.

How can I do this? I've done more than a bit of research and can't find anything that would work without us switching over to maven and using a plugin, which would be less than ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you set the build number as classifier in 'jar' closure?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way in gradle to detect if one is in a Jenkins environment, let alone get the build number.